# How to use custom jars in spark-submit --packages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I have a PySpark project which is doing spark structured streaming, to get the query metrics I have created a java project which listens to the microbatch events and logs the data in a log files. The logging works when I pass the jar as a file and using --jar to read it in spark-submit.

But, this process has manual work involved after where jar has to be uploaded manually. To solve it
uploaded the jar in JFrog repository. Now when running the spark-submit command I have added --repositories and also added the coordinate in --packages which already includes few packages like kafka, avro etc. All the packages downloads from the jfrog but when it reaches myjar it throws below error, but the repo url from log if if I try from browser it actually downloads the jar and pom as well!!!

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: <myjar>;<version>

    ==== central: tried

      https://<repo>/myjar.pom

      -- artifact <myjar>.jar:

      https://<repo>/myjar.jar

    ==== repo-1: tried

      https://<repo>/myjar.pom

      -- artifact <myjar>.jar:

      https://<repo>/myjar.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.spark.extension#<myjar>;<version>: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.spark.extension#<myjar>;<verion>: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1047)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

EDIT-
Taken from EMR  (some of the url/names are omitted)-

```
spark-submit --name "A Adapter" --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --repositories https://<jfrog repo>/artifactory/all/ --packages com.spark.extension:spark-listeners:0.3.8,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.22,software.amazon.cloudwatchlogs:aws-embedded-metrics:2.0.0-beta-1 --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 12g --executor-memory 12g --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=6 --files s3://<url>/log4j.properties,s3://<url>/logging.json --conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=s3://<url>/libs.zip#app-site-packages --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONPATH=app-site-packages --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_APP_NAME=A Adapter" --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CLUSTER_STUB=dev-b1 --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_EMF_SERVICE_NAME=A Adapter" --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_EMF_SERVICE_TYPE=dev-b1-emr --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_EMF_LOG_GROUP_NAME=dev-b1-spark-structured-stream-logs --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_EMF_LOG_STREAM_NAME=dev-b1-spark-structured-stream-logs --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_EMF_AGENT_ENDPOINT=udp://127.0.0.1:25888 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions= --conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=app-site-packages --py-files s3://<url>/libs.zip,s3://<url>/jobs.zip,s3://<url>/.env s3://<url>/main.py --job acc
```

Comment: Can you please provide you spark-submit command?

Comment: Hi @GuyMelul I have added the spark-submit in the post

Comment: Your command looks good to me. you might want to check if permission is an issue. opening in the brower might use your existing authentication and allow it. test using curl and see if you can download those files

Comment: Validated it, doesn't look like access issue, it would have given 401. Also, all other repositories are downloaded only this fails. Is there any specific way to build a jar to be used in --package? @GuyMelul

Comment: still stuck with this